# libgdx clickable image not working

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a menu screen in libgdx and I had a text button that started a new game like this.

```
textButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        g.setScreen( new level1(g));
    }
});
```

It looked like crap so I changed it to an image.

```
playbuttontexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/playbutton.png"));
playbuttontexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

TextureRegion playbuttonregion = new TextureRegion(playbuttontexture, 0, 0, 512, 256);//powers of 2

playbutton = new Image(playbuttonregion);
playbutton.setSize(512,256);
playbutton.setBounds(width/2-playbutton.getWidth()/2, height/2-playbutton.getHeight()/2, 512, 256);
//playbutton.setOrigin(playbutton.getWidth()/2, playbutton.getHeight()/2);
playbutton.setPosition(width/2-playbutton.getWidth()/2, height/2-playbutton.getHeight()/2);
```

and

```
playbutton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        g.setScreen( new level1(g));
    }
});
```

Now when I click it nothing happens? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change it to a `ClickListener` and use the `clicked(...)` method instead. An image doesn't fire a `changed()` event.

Comment: @noone you should put your answers in the answer section.  Even if they're short.

Comment: @P.T. Yes, sorry. Sometimes I just don't have time to write more than half a sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `Image` does not fire a `changed(...)` event anymore. This event is only fired by the `TextButton` you've used before when the status changes from clicked to not-clicked and the other way around. It can also be fired in other cases, since it is kind of a "generic" event, as the JavaDoc states, but that varies from actor to actor.

Change it to a `ClickListener` and use the `clicked(...)` method instead. This event should be fired by all actors in the `scene2d.ui` package.

Answer (score 0):

for me this is what it looks like when I implemented the code ( I was having a similar issue. noone did a great job at pointing me to the right places to look. )

```
playbutton.addListener( new ClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void clicked (InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
    //your code to do stuff when the button is clicked  

    }

});
```