# LibGDX How to know if anybody clicks on texture

Tags: image, button, click, libgdx, textures

i was using that if anybody touches on position where is the texture, do something. but it is the bad, i want to make a resizable game, because no everybody has a HD and above screens(and on androids, its worse..). So, i have applicated the projection matrix, so if i am resizing it it looks good, but if i resize my screen, the button is bigger or smaller than it was, so the positions are not right now. so my question is, is any way to set a OnClickListener to a texture? So it would work if i resize the screen.

Or maybe, i think, there could be an button, too. but i dont know how to set a texture of button.

Comment: You could try adding a listener to an image.

Comment: I am just trying to do that, it doesnt work, i am trying to set the listener with a help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863138/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-make-image-touchable-in-libgdx but, nothing is happening, i have created a Touch class in which i am implementing InputAdapter, and then i set the inputprocessor, maybe i am doing something wrong... where i should put the Image.setListener ? to a touch class, or to my Core class?

Comment: You can start with posting some code here.

Comment: So? look at my code pls:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this listener:

```
image.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            //smth
        }
    });
```

Comment: This code does not work. I would see a full code pls(the create, and render). I actually tried to use this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574821/libgdx-clickable-image-not-working . they suggested to him to use Clicked() func, and.. it works for me, but if i am clicking only in the left side of the button. It does not work for full button image. so i do not know if there is a problem or where. :D

Comment: what do you mean left side? could you visualize it? are you using viewport?

Comment: Ah, now it works, i dont know why it did not worked. So now, if i am resizing the screen, it doesnt apply. so if i make my screen smaller, the clickable space is not in the image.. how to fixthat? call initialize image in resize();? btw. if i set the size of screen before programm starts, it works.. So, can i expect that if the programm will be ran on mobile devices with another screens, will it work? :) :D

Comment: You should use viewport, it scales everything automatically. If i helped you please accept the answer and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

So, in create func i created an image :

```
Image backImage = new Image(backTexture); //backTexture is my button texture
backImage.setX(0);
backImage.setY(0);
backImage.setWidth(800);
backImage.setHeight(480);
```

then in render function, i have:

```
backImage.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
    {
        //do something
        return true;
    }
});
```

and, i created a new class, in which i am implementing InputAdapter, and in create function i also call

```
Touch t; // my touch class 
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(t);
```

so, it should overwrite the TouchDown function from Touch.class, but it does not work

Comment: Why would you create another class? You add the image to a stage, and set the input processor to the stage.
    `stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
stage.addActor(image);`

Comment: Yes, now i am doing it better

Comment: Yes, it is, but i am not using touchDown(), i am using clicked()